# Why cannot read csv file by PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I'm using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet to read a csv file like :

```
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);
```

It error: `Warning: mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments`.

But it works well with xlsx file.

I tried use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv but it's same error.
I tried dump $file, I see mimeType is `text/csv`, but when $file->getMimeType() is return `text/plain`. This makes me cannot validate the upload file (I just allow user upload xlsx/csv file). I think it maybe cause error cannot read csv file?

**Edit:** It is my fault. `load()` receive arguments as a string but I pass a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadFile (because it's work with xlsx file). So change `$file` to `$file->getPathName()` and it works well.
But with validate file, I think I have to accept text/plain, does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file MIME type with the `$file->getClientMimeType()` method. This will give you the "text/csv" string you are looking for.